# How to determine in Chrome Dev what CSS rules are from a WordPress Child Theme

Tags: wordpress-theming, google-chrome-devtools

When you inspect the markup of a Wordpress site that has a child theme, the display for the Elements tab when you inspect the markup shows CSS rules from both the main style.css and the child's style.css as simply style.css.  In the image below, for example, the a:hover color of #345678 is made on line 16 of the child theme while the a:hover text-decoration of underline is made on line 1116 of the original 2014 theme. But there's no indication in the Chrome display which file is supplying which rule.  Is there  way to make this show up?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could know this by hovering over the text that displays the line info. On hovering, the absolute path of the file from which the CSS rule is being set will be displayed.